# failing to launch node app config file

Tags: javascript, node.js, config

I am totally new to nodeJs. I am using 
`node 5.0.0` cloned a [repo](https://github.com/ubimix/mosaic-techonmap-server) and launched the command :

```
node ./app.js -c config.yaml
```

but I get this error

```
node_modules/q/q.js:155
                throw e;
            ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
    at Object.parse (native)
    at yaml2json (/home/../mosaic-techonmap-server/source/config.access.js:13:21)
    at module.exports (/home/../mosaic-techonmap-server/source/config.access.js:152:23)
    at /home/../app.js:89:45
    at _fulfilled (/home/../node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/../mosaic-techonmap-server/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/../mosaic-techonmap-server/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
    at /home/../mosaic-techonmap-server/node_modules/q/q.js:877:14
    at runSingle (/home/../mosaic-techonmap-server/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/home/../mosaic-techonmap-server/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
```

Someone has an idea ?

EDIT: here's the code of the `config.yaml` file

```
---
# Configuration sample file for Jingo (YAML)
application:
    title: "CartoWiki"
server:
    hostname: "localhost"
    port: 6067
    localOnly: false
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:6067"
authentication:
    google:
      enabled: true
    twitter:
      enabled: true
      oauthkeys:
        consumerKey : ''
        consumerSecret : ''
      cacheExpire: 3600000
    facebook:
      enabled: true
      oauthkeys:
        clientID : ''
        clientSecret : ''
    alone:
      enabled: false
      username: ""
      passwordHash: ""
      email: ""
twitterClient:
    consumerKey : ''
    consumerSecret : ''
    accessTokenKey : ''
    accessTokenSecret : ''
```

Comment: did you run `npm install` before?

Comment: Can you not create an issue on the author's github?

Comment: post the `config.yaml` code also

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam I have just poster the config file

Comment: yes @AndreiNemes yes I ran `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

I Cloned the repo and when I tried your `config.yaml` I'm able to reproduce the issue.

In the `config.access.js:152:23` it excepts `config.accessRules` but your yaml file doesn't have `accessRules` so the `accessRules` object becomes undefined since the error `Unexpected token u`

Add the `accessRules` to your config then you should not get this error.